# React Router structuring - passing functions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm quite new to reactjs and was just wondering if there is any easy way to display information from the same component to different routes. In the following code as an example I have just two functions that are just returning divs full of text, and calling them and rendering them right away (in the class or in the router) would just have them be on the same "page".

I've tried passing the ref by props but they always ended up undefined. I figured a state change would be awkward since there is no real "event". I'm using create-react-app, react-routerv4, and react-bootstrap.

In App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar/NavBar.js';
import Band from './Components/Text/Band.js';
import { Router, BrowserRouter, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="RenderRouter">
          <Route exact path='/' component={NavBar}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={ControlledCarousel}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>

          //<Route exact path='/Artists/ArtistX' component={Band}/>          
          <Route exact path='/Artists/Artist1' component={NavBar}/>
          <Route exact path='/Artists/Artist1' render={props => <Band band1text = {this.props.band1text} />}/>

          <Route exact path='/Artists/Artist2' component={NavBar}/>
          <Route exact path='/Artists/Artist2' render={props => <Band band2text = {this.props.band2text} />}/>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In Band.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Band.css';

class Band extends Component {
//Constructor for state change would go here
    band1text(props) {
      return(
        <div id="band1Text"  className="BandText">
          <h1>"The best riffs!</h1>
        </div>
        );
      };

    band2text(props) {
      return(
        <div id="band2Text"  className="BandText">
          <p>More info coming soon! Check out the interview!</p>
        </div>
        );
      };
      //Create handlers to call functions, and pass reference?
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="BandDescription">
        //calling in DOM render object, can't pass props from here?
        //{this.props.band1text()} = compiler error
          {this.band1text()}
          {this.band2text()}
        </div>
       );
    }
}

export default Band;
```

It would probably be easier to just have separate components and classes for every piece of each route (i.e, BandX.js, CarouselX.js) but that could get verbose and one would have to import many files. I'm using react to build a music player component for the app as well, that's why I'm not just using standard JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing something like this in your Band component render:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className="BandDescription">
      {this.props.band1text && this.band1text()}
      {this.props.band2text && this.band2text()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way it checks for the prop before running whichever method. If both methods are passed, both functions will return. And you shouldn't need to pass `props` to those methods. Try writing them as arrow functions so they will be bound `band1text = () => { ... }`, you will still be able to access `this.props.band1text` from inside the method.

Comment: I see. I converted to arrow functions to bind them and passed both methods still to no avail. The routed pages compile and load okay minus the text. What's funny is that when I try to put console.log('print statement'); in the return method of Band.js I get an unexpected token. I can't get a printed string log or the value of this.props.bandXtext to print out in either method as well.

Comment: Try putting some actual text into the prop you pass to the component, in App.js `<Band band1text={"some actual text"}`. You won't have `this.props.band1text` in App.js unless you pass it like that in a prop when you render the App component (Alternatively `<App band1text="whatever" />` would pass the prop through `App.js` the way you have it written now). Then you can access `this.props.band1text` anywhere in a Band component that was passed that prop.

Comment: Ah, this worked perfectly, thanks! I see App.js needs something as the prop to render, not just the prop itself.

Answer (score 1):

The props would be undefined because there is no props with bandText being passed down to App component. Routes are nested in App component and this.props.band1Text means you are expecting to read from props passed to App. Try passing band1Text and band2Text as props to App component. 
Also to read a props that's not a function just use {this.props.band1Text} in the Band.js component